# can mysql user be blocked on the local server but have remote acces?

Tags: mysql, permissions

So at work we have a windows server running mysql, the IT guy got fired but he supposedly left root password.

Try to login with root user:
  **- Locally:** *"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

**- Remotely:** *"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'hp-01' (using password: YES)*

Beacause i've been using a .net app which connects to that server I thought I'd give it a try with that user. it went like this:

**- Locally:** *"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'adminpect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*

**- Remotely:** I stablished connection, but because it's not an admin user I only have limited acces to one database.

All this i tried from the command line and mysql workbench and in both I get the same results.

For the record I have very basic mysql knowledge and I've been searching all over the internet for this but have'nt had much luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible that an user only have access from serveral locations. Did you try just google 'reset root password windows server'? Or just contact that guy who installed it. Is that a dumb idea?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13677436)

Comment: "reset root password" on http://forums.mysql.com/ comes up with over 300 hits.  It is a common question, with a single answer.  It is also a page in the online docs.

Comment: Well I've been trying to reset the root password with [this][1] but it's been a little tricky in this case, I'm still trying. And for about contacting this person you said... the thing is he was fired and I'm not gonna get any info from this guy.


  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html